# R RJDBC oracle dbWritetable, value too large for column maximum: 255

Tags: r, oracle, rjdbc

one column of my data frame contains pieces of text, characters is more than 255, when i use dbWritetable to oracle, i got this error:

```
    Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
    execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (ORA-12899: value too large for column "DWTEST"."PCP_DOCS"."WORDS" (actual: 341, maximum: 255)
    )
```

anyone can help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please publish the update query that you are posting?

Answer (score 1):

The column is capable of accepting only 255 characters. And you are trying to  populate it with 341 characters. Hence, the error.

Comment: dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection, "temp", pcp_cust1) , one culumn of pcp_cust1  over the capable, how can i fix it, or any solution? thanks @shruti1810

Comment: In pcp_cust1, please check the values which are getting entered for the column which is throwing error. Please reduce the column contents. Or, in the database, increase the column size to `>341` for the column throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "DWTEST"."PCP_DOCS"."WORDS" (actual: 341, maximum: 255)

The error means that the column `WORDS` in the table `PCP_DOCS` was created with a **maximum limit** of 255 characters. You are trying to update the column with a value having **more than 255 characters**, i.e. 341 characters, and thus the update is failing.

Assuming the column data type is **VARCHAR2**, you could **modify** the column to **increase the size**:

```
ALTER TABLE pcp_docs MODIFY (words VARCHAR2(500));
```

For example,

```
SQL> create table t(col varchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values('abc');
insert into t values('abc')
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "LALIT"."T"."COL" (actual: 3, maximum: 2)


SQL>
SQL> alter table t modify(col varchar2(10));

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values('abc');

1 row created.

SQL>
```